# Why would a higher load factor in HashMap decrease the space overhead

Tags: java, hashmap

From the java documentation: "As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good trade off between time and space costs. **Higher values decrease the space overhead** but increase the lookup cost"

Why it decrease the space overhead? isnt the extra nodes in the buckets with equivalent size of the extra array size?

(in the end the number of entries will be the same!)

Comment: The ratio of the number of entries to the array size _is_ the load factor.  When it's higher, there are fewer extra array slots relative to the number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

The load factor controls how full the map can become, before it's capacity is doubled.

Let's assume you have an ideal hash function with proper dispersal among buckets. Let's say you have a map with 100 capacity and a load factor of 0.75. This means that when you add elements to fill 75 buckets, it's allocated capacity is doubled i.e. becomes 200. So with 75 actual buckets, you've allocated capacity of 200. Overhead i.e. wasted space = 125

Now, let's say we have another map with capacity 100 and load factor 0.5. This means that by the time the map is populated 50 actual buckets, it's capacity is doubled. So for 50 entries, the capacity is now 200. Overhead = 150.

With higher load capacity the opposite happens i.e. you have less wasted space.